# Is there a way to watch for a selection to change in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that comes on to the screen in a popup. Basically it slides in from the left and shows the hierarchy available.

When it comes on screen, I select an item within it to represent the current location. Before today, this all worked.

Today I added a `UITextView` as a header to the table. Since then, my selection is acting strangely. When the `UITableViewController` appears, I can see my selected row get selected briefly, but it immediately becomes unselected. Calls to `indexPathForSelectedRow` return nil.

Is there a way to be alerted whenever the selection changes in `UITableView`? I know to use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to keep track of when the user selects an item, but this problem is happening without user input. I'm assuming I've done something incorrect within the code, but I'm trying to track it down without posting all my code here.

**Edit**

*Apropos of nothing*, I did find that the problem goes away if I remove the Navigation Controller that I had added to the `UITableViewController`. This was because I had not set the property `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to `NO`. By adding the Navigation Controller, the `UITableViewController` was getting loaded differently, causing the property to actually be used.

However, I still would like to know how to be alerted to table view selection changes.

Comment: Implement `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @rmaddy, and it never got called.

Comment: Show the code. And point out what you changed since it was working.

Comment: You probably did not set yourself up as the table view's delegate.

Comment: @DuncanC, that is a valid theory. But the delegate is set, and other delegate methods are being called.

Comment: You could use make your cell your UIVIewController, by delegate. (cell.delegate = self, in the CellForRowAtIndex..). So whenever the cells are taped or changes, the actuel cell will call The main UIVIewController, with his index.